# "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes" in json file

Tags: python, json, quotes

Here is the json file

```
{"pre_trigger": 4, "sampling frequency": 1652, "record length": 15.0, 
"sensors": 
[{"model": "393B05", "serial": "46978", "sensitivity": 10030, "sensitivity_units": "mV/g", "sensor_type": "Accelerometer", "units": "g", "location": [7.01, -0.19, 0], "location_units": "m", "direction": [0, 0, 1], "trigger": true, "trigger_value": 0.005, "max_val": 0.45, "min_val": -0.45, "comments": "Inside B122 next to bookshelf", "channel": "cDAQ1Mod2/ai0"}],

[{"model": "393B05", "serial": "47085", "sensitivity": 9980, "sensitivity_units": "mV/g", "sensor_type": "Accelerometer", "units": "g", "location": [9.65, -0.19, 0], "location_units": "m", "direction": [0, 0, 1], "trigger": true, "trigger_value": 0.005, "max_val": 0.45, "min_val": -0.45, "comments": "Inside B122 under the whiteboard", "channel": "cDAQ1Mod2/ai1"}] 

"parameters": {"general": [], "specific": ["Walking direction", "Person ID"]}}
```

I'm not one to understand coding so I don't know where this error truly is coming from. I'm running a command the following commands

```
daq = DAQ()
daq.load_setup('json.fname')
```

Which returns the property error. There are no single quotes in the json file, so I truly don't know where the problem is. Below is where the error calls back to.

```
 def load_setup(self,fname='setup.json'):
    """
    Opens the JSON file containing the setup parameters for the experiment.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : str
        File that the parameters for the experiment were saved into (JSON file)

    """
    import json

    with open(fname, 'r') as setup_file:
        setup_data = json.load(setup_file)

    self.fs = setup_data['sampling frequency']
    self.record_length = setup_data['record length']
    self.sensors = setup_data['sensors']
    self.parameters = setup_data['parameters']
    self.pre_trigger = setup_data['pre_trigger']
```

Comment: There aren't sufficient information so we can try your code case and  understand problem. Can you add more codes, like that of the class and explain better what you are trying of achieving with the two lines. However let me try guessing, I think you are accessing a property that there isn't on **json** object if you function executes with `exec()` the passed string.

Comment: Yes I will try. I'll add where the error calls back to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply do not have valid JSON (there isn't anything wrong with your Python code). You're not using the array functionality correctly. A JSON array looks like this:

```
{"some_array": ["first item", "second item", ..., "last item"]}
```

it *does not* look like this (which is what you had and why you get the error you're getting):

```
{"some_array": ["first item"], ["second item"], ..., ["last item"]}
```

Long story short, your list items are comma delimted *inside* the square brackets. Here's what your JSON should look like (`sensor` array fixed, and pretty-printed):

```
{
    "pre_trigger": 4,
    "sampling frequency": 1652,
    "record length": 15.0,
    "sensors":
    [
        {
            "model": "393B05",
            "serial": "46978",
            "sensitivity": 10030,
            "sensitivity_units": "mV/g",
            "sensor_type": "Accelerometer",
            "units": "g",
            "location": [7.01, -0.19, 0],
            "location_units": "m",
            "direction": [0, 0, 1],
            "trigger": true,
            "trigger_value": 0.005,
            "max_val": 0.45,
            "min_val": -0.45,
            "comments": "Inside B122 next to bookshelf",
            "channel": "cDAQ1Mod2/ai0"
        },
        {
            "model": "393B05",
            "serial": "47085",
            "sensitivity": 9980,
            "sensitivity_units": "mV/g",
            "sensor_type": "Accelerometer",
            "units": "g",
            "location": [9.65, -0.19, 0],
            "location_units": "m",
            "direction": [0, 0, 1],
            "trigger": true,
            "trigger_value": 0.005,
            "max_val": 0.45,
            "min_val": -0.45,
            "comments": "Inside B122 under the whiteboard",
            "channel": "cDAQ1Mod2/ai1"
        }
    ],

    "parameters": {
        "general": [],
        "specific":
        [
            "Walking direction",
            "Person ID"
        ]
    }
}
```

I recommend always keeping your JSON pretty-printed (even on disk), as it makes it easier to read/understand. Part of the appeal of the JSON format is that you can easily eyeball it as a human.

The rest of your code that you posted worked fine after this fix.

HTH.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: @newtothis Glad to have helped! If it's the right answer, you can also accept it (checkmark next to where you've upvoted).